# Output in grep command

Tags: regex, grep

I'm new with regexp and I believe this is a beginner's glitch in getting the output.

My regexp for **AB(CD) digits/digits** is: `[A-Z]+[^a-zA-Z0-9][A-Z]+[^a-zA-Z0-9] [0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]+`

Grep command is: `grep "regexp" xyz.txt`

there's no output to above command, but when I use sublime editor for same regex, i gets the desired result. Tried many attempts with grep command , the only time it gave results is when I deleted the `[0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]+` portion from regex because there is a space in between but still the results were not desired. Tried  `grep -e` and `grep --regexp=` too, no results.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong or the correct syntax for this command. Much grateful.

Edit:

The data looks like the following:

`AB(C.D.) nnnnn/nnnnnn
A.B(C.D.) nnnnnn/nnnnn 
A.B.(CD) nnnnn/nnnnnn
AB(CD) nnnnn/nnnnnn
AAB(CD) nnnnn/nnnnnn
....
....
further P & C`

I was looking only for AB(CD) nnnn/nnnnnn. Would really like to learn the correct expression.

Comment: Use `grep -E "pattern"`, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/KJrBXY). If a space is an issue, try replacing with `[[:space:]]`

Comment: yep, it worked perfectly, thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew, i was really scratching my head :)

Comment: My comment is rather ambguous, if the answer below is enough, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grep -E as it switches grep into a special mode so that the expression is evaluated as an ERE (Extended Regular Expression) as opposed to its normal pattern matching.

Comment: That will cause output to be produced but it doesn't explain why (the `+`) and it won't fix the other problems with the regexp. @lawsome post a followup with concise, testable input and expected output if you'd like to learn how to write your regexp correctly.

Comment: @EdMorton , what change in regex you'll suggest ?

Comment: It depends what your input looks like and what output you want to produce. The placeholder values `AB(CD) nnnn/nnnnnn` in your question don't help much and are no substitute for concrete sample input AND expected output that includes strings you want to match in context with strings you don't, especially rainy day cases with potential partial matches, etc. Come up with concise, testable sample input and expected output and we can help you but you've already accepted this answer to this question so post a new question.